# No signal on brand new monitor, Nvidia GPU

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

2 days ago I got a new 1440p 144hz Benq EX2780q FreeSync Premium monitor,

I when I first installed, I struggled for 15 min trying different hdmi cables and hdmi ports (hdmi1, hdmi2), and pulling the plug on/off on the monitor until I got it to work,

after I noticed that just slightly touching the hdmi cable may interrupt the signal, and I never seen bios or windows loading with this monitor only when the windows is loaded I can have the chance to receive signal

on the next day I got signal when windows loaded

today I'm not getting signal anymore

I'm using my old monitor now, which doesn't get any of these problems (Benq EW2430)

I tried connecting it on a samsung laptop (intel CPU no video card) and it always works

on the desktop PC I have GTX 1660 super

the monitor has FreeSync Premium, could this matter ?

Comment: Try a DP cable.

Comment: I've managed to get it working for now, using the old hdmi cable which feels a bit tighter, but I only get signal when windows loads, I can never see bios or windows loading with this monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDMI cable works while in Windows if it fits properly (tight).

Using **DP** cable now, which works (shows signal) in BIOS as well.